# Cannot install PyYAML on Travis CI?

Tags: python, macos, travis-ci, pyyaml

I need `pyyaml` for Travis, installing through `pip`:

https://github.com/elliotchance/CollectionFactory/blob/1.1/hide-jsonstring/.travis.yml#L7

However it dumps a bunch of errors:

https://s3.amazonaws.com/archive.travis-ci.org/jobs/54833518/log.txt

I found nothing with googling and I can install the same requirement on my mac.

Since it's only for reading configuration data, speed is not a concern. Is there a pure python implementation of a YAML reader I can use?

Answer (score 1):

PyYAML includes a pure python implementation, but it tries to install some C based to speed things up.

I do the same in my enhanced version of PyYAML ([ruamel.yaml](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.yaml)), but in a different way. I also try to install the fast C reader/emitter, but do not use it for my roundtrip, comment preserving, enhancements, those are pure python only.

I forked your project and was able to successfully run it on Travis by replacing in `.travis.yml`:

```
- brew install libyaml
- sudo python -m easy_install pyyaml
```

by:

```
- sudo pip install ruamel.yaml
```

and change in `generate_tests.py`:

```
import yaml
```

to:

```
import ruamel.yaml as yaml
```